# Как я могу вывести дни из диапазона дат MySQL

Tags: mysql

У меня есть диапазон дат, в таблице:

1. 2021-09-01
2. 2022-02-07

Мне необходимо вывести таблицу вида:

```
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```

и т.д (т.е грубо говоря все дни в месяце)
Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Делайте это на клиенте, его средствами. Или просто хардкодом. PIVOT в MySQL штука не самая простая.

Comment: вам нужно сделать это как таблицу для календаря (строчка - 7 ячеек) или вывести в одну строку с оформлением выше?

Comment: @AnastasiaVovremya вывести одну строчку с оформление выше, для каждого месяца

Comment: Группируйте `SELECT DAYOFMONTH(\`created_at\`) as \`day\`, [ДРУГИЕ ПОЛЯ] FROM \`[ТАБЛИЦА]\` WHERE \`created_at\` > "[ДАТА]" AND \`created_at\` < "[ДАТА]" GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(\`created_at\`)`. Выведет по дням что у Вас там есть. Или нужно прям в ответе чтобы так выстраивало?